# Performance difference between max and greater than in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, date, oracle10g, aggregate

While designing a table which have impact based on date (e.g. Currency Rate) which one is better?

1. Effective date (Find out max(Effective date) and get the current value)
2. From Date - To Date condition (With greater than equals sysdate)

Rgrds.

Comment: what DBMS you are using? please retag your question

Comment: It will be easier to help you if you provide the structure of your table and query 1 and 2.

Comment: 1: seq_id, currency_code, currency_name, currency_rate,base_currency_code, effective_date. 2:seq_id, currency_code, currency_name, currency_rate,base_currency_code,from_date, to_date(may be null)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends. You have a table representing changes to a particular entity, and you want to record when the entity changed, and when the change was replaced by a subsequent change.

*1.* If you record just the Effective Date for each event, INSERTs are simpler: they don't need to find the earlier record to update it. However, querying becomes more complex - you'll need to run a window over the dataset to find which record is applicable at any one time, potentially resulting in poorer performance.

Another downside is that this model is open-ended; you can't record a currency as "permanently closed" (which you could do if you had an End date).

*2.* If you record the Start and End dates for each event, queries are simpler: you only need to look at each row individually to know whether it is "current" as of any point in time or not. INSERTs, however, are slightly more complex - when you insert a new event, you have to update the earlier event to mark its End date.

This model is closed-ended; you can put a End date on the final event and have no "open" record.